# Is it necessary to close ZODB connections after only reading data

Tags: zodb

I am using ZODB for my python object persistence. I am using web2py as a framework.

The ZODB database I am using is accessed only for reads. I have written the code for opening the database inside my models. The `connection.root()` object is then cached in RAM so it stays there for other requests.

My question is, is it necessary to close a ZODB database if it is used only for read access and there are no pending writes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you don't need to close it. Each open connection does consume a little memory etc, but it sounds like you aren't going to have thousands of them anyway, just one per web2py process

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to close it, but you should run `connection.cacheMinimize()` regularly, if you want to avoid, that the cached objects eats up your memory. If you're also writing data and commit regularly, you can skip that, as `commit()` includes `cacheMinimize()`.